# Heaptrack is giving empty heap dump

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, heap-memory, heap-dump

During my analysis of the memory for my service , getting this warning and its generating a empty zip file even after my service does many activities and lot of memory allocate/deallocate.

(I' am running heaptrack on my server service, I sent all the required file of heaptrack manually from my local to router)

```
`
heaptrack injection via GDB, this might take some time.
warning: File "/lib64/libthread_db-1.0.so" auto-loading has been declined by your
auto-load safe-path' set to"Sdebugdir:$datadir/auto-load".

warning: Unable to find libthread db matching inferior's thread library,
thread debugging will not be available.

No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command.
Heaptrack finished! Now run the following to investigate the data:
heaptrack -analyze "/var/tmp/heaptrack.\<service_name\>.11915.gz"\

ls -lt /var/tmp/heaptrack.\<service_name\>.11915.gz
rw-r--r- - 1 root root 0 Jul 24 17:18 /var/tmp/heaptrack.\<service name\>.gz
`
```

complied with command = ./heaptrack --pid <pid_number>

How to resolve this issue?

Tried matching ( router service and local  )

1. All the type of binaries files
2. Linux version
3. OS version

My best guess is something related to this error "No symbol table is loaded."